# GTX 950M no longer detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel

Asus R510VX-DM169D
i5-6300HQ
GTX950M

Working perfectly until 2 weeks ago, ubuntu no longer detect the graphics card and automatically switched to intel graphics i tried reinstalling drivers and all i find on google, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect its either a kernel issue, I have a rx580 gpu and since a recent kernel update have suffered massive lagging issues when using.